# What are the supported values for PHP zend.script_encoding?

Tags: php, encoding, hhvm, hiphop

[PHP.net - `zend.script_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.script-encoding) states:

> This value will be used unless a `declare(encoding=...)` directive appears at the top of the script. When ISO-8859-1 i[n]compatible encoding is used, both `zend.multibyte` and `zend.script_encoding` must be used.

What are the supported values for `zend.script_encoding`? Are the supported encodings hard-coded or configurable?

Also, if we do not specify any value for `zend.script_encoding`, what's the default assumed?

Does behavior vary between different engines/platforms?

Comment: @Dagon, What's the encoding assumed when the value is NULL?